# why the Issue tracking list has its Description field's internal name as "Comment"

Tags: 2013, list, administration, site-column, issue-tracking

I have added an Issue tracking list inside my team site collection. and when i checked its built-in fields, i  have noted that the Description field internal name is "comment" instead of being "Description". i noticed this as i wrote a powershell script and i was not able to reference the Description field using "Description" internal name. here is the internal name for the field when i access it from the site settings page :-

[image]

so can anyone adivce what is the reason behind this ? is there is any ofcourse ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they decided to reuse an existing site column they created as part of the application. There are other instances of this most notably, many content types share the Keywords site column. This has been the case for several product revisions.

Comment: but this is confusing a bit,, taking into consideration that there is a another column named "comments" with S which will store the version comment !!

Comment: And just like Created By is actually Author. This is just how it is.

Comment: Yes it is confusing. We often say, "Because...SharePoint!"